# Is there any free usable component for workflow editor/designer?

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-engine

I am trying to find a .NET component that allows GUI (drag-and-drop) workflow design, and I need it as a part of a bigger software so I prefer it to be a usable component. What I imagine is it is similar to the GUI used to design workflows in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. Is there any such component? I tried searching for a while and didn't have any luck.
The best I could find are these

- http://www.wareprise.com/2009/03/13/list-of-top-open-source-bpm-workflow-solution/
- http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

but I don't think any of the items in those list are compatible with my requirements. has anyone been looking for this and found a good component? I am looking for a free one, and open source is even better if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workflow designer from Windows workflow foundation can be used as a control (re-hosted) and comes with all the funcatuionality:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835242.aspx

Comment: if the article in that link is too confusing, try reading this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489440.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can host the Visual Studio workflow designer in you own application. [This article](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fvincentlaine.developpez.com%2Ftuto%2Fdotnet%2Fwf-designer%2F) explains how to do it (it's originally in French but Google Translate usually gives a decent translation)

Answer (score 2):

Crainiate ERM Diagram is now [Open Diagram](http://opendiagram.codeplex.com/). It's open sourced under the rather undesirable GPLv2 license.

Comment: I can probably change that licence now if required.

Comment: Source code now here https://github.com/jameswestgate/opendiagram

Answer (score -1):

It's not free, but the best you will find is [Crainiate ERM Diagram](http://www.crainiate.net/products/erm4/default.htm)

Comment: "Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)" on that URL

Comment: "The best you will fin"? I sincerely hope not. The wordt about Crainiate is that there is absolutely no community behind this. You just cannot find any information about it.

Comment: This got open sourced and moved to opendiagram.codeplex.com - but version 5.0 never moved out of beta. No one stepped up to help and I couldn't do it for free. However version 4 is very stable and also included in the source tree.

Comment: Probably I would try to use d3.js in a browser now though.

Comment: @JamesWestgate : Where can I find version 4 of Open Diagram?

Comment: @AbhijeetNagre It is in the source code under version 4.1

Answer (score -1):

check out http://www.cDevWorkflow.com next generation workflow engine with graphical designer for .net applications and developers